# reading variables in struct type in for loop

Tags: c++, struct

I'w writing piece of code and I should read variables from for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NumOfStudents 100
#define NumOfCourses 15

struct Student{
  int stdnum, FieldCode, age;
  double average, res[NumOfCourses];
  char name[20];          //First and Last name length                                                                                                                          
};

int main(){
  struct Student students[NumOfStudents];
  int i;
  cout << "\tNAME || STUDENT-NUMBER || FIELD-CODE || AGE";
  for(i=0; i<NumOfStudents; i++){
    cout << "\nSTUDENT #" << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> students[i].name[20] >> students[i].stdnum >> students[i].FieldCode >> students[i].age;                                                                            
    //    cin >> students[i].name[20];                                                                                                                                          
  }
}
```

EDIT:
output is:

```
./st 
    NAME || STUDENT-NUMBER || FIELD-CODE || AGE
STUDENT #1: test

STUDENT #2: 
STUDENT #3: 
STUDENT #4:
.
.
.
STUDENT #100:
```

I can just enter name of first student and loop doesn't work correctly
what is the problem?

Comment: can you please post the output of terminal?

Comment: use `std::string` instead of `char[20]` for `name`

Comment: @i_m_optional of course I did it

Comment: Note: Unless the student has no surname (or has only a cur name), even with the answers currently below you're program will still falter with John Smith. the comment in the code says `name` is for first *and* last name. You still have some work to do if that is the case. if not, they're all spot-on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cin >> students[i].name[20];`

It shouldn't be an array of `20`. It means your entered first character is stored in index `20th` location which is in-correct and can cause undefined behavior as `name` array is indexed from `0` to `19` only.

Rather it should be `cin >> students[i].name`, which writes into base address of array `name`

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to write

```
cin >> students[i].name
```

Since it is a 1D array, `subscript` should not be used in getting input.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> students[i].name[20]
```

This part is wrong. This command reads **one character** from standard input and stores it in the 20th position in `name` (i.e. in the byte right after the array `name`). You want to use:

```
cin >> students[i].name >> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In line "cin >> students[i].name[20]".

You can't use name[20] as input variable for a character string as it points to a character at index 20, which also do not exists in your case as char name[20] stores in indexes 0-19.

Correct format:

cin>>students[i].name;

To read string of characters or name as a string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use `students[i].name` without the index. Your syntax tries to insert the single character it reads from the terminal beyond the end of the char array and thus messing with the pointer (note that you should make sure that the input is truncated anyway).

Second, you should type all input parameters for each student, you cannot just insert their name. So input would be:

```
$ ./st
STUDENT #1: TestName 3456 1 15
```

If that's not intended behaviour, you might want to do multiple `cin >> variable` statemates.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make it more clear. Is it that you are not able to enter the details after the first name is typed in? Or is it that the loop is exited before the entire operation is performed?

In you code, there's a problem, I guess

```
students[i].name[20]
```

here only one character is read. This should be replaced in cin with

```
students[i].name
```

Also if you are not able to enter the details after the first iteration, try to give fflush() or setbuf() to clear the input buffer.

Also if you have to read a string with spaces, try to use cin.getline() or gets(). The format for these are available in the net.

Thank you